# jQuery UI slider widget + fancybox + zooming/scaling

Tags: jquery, css, slider, zooming, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using jquery UI slider (http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

I need to make scaling/zooming on the whole site.
For scaling in IE+Chrome im using css style - "zoom".

All works fine in zoomed state, the problem is in slider, sliding just not triggering by clicking on him(when his parent is zoomed).

Here is the example of what i mean - http://jsfiddle.net/8hbMx/

```
<style>
    .slider{
      width: 363px;;
      height: 15px;
      margin-left: 40px;
  }
    #test{
      zoom: 50%;
}
 </style>
 <div id="test">
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.slider').slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        width: 50,
        value: 1
    });
</script>
```

Here is how i fire zooming:

```
                $(window).resize(debouncer(function(e) {
                    scale_elements();
                }));
```

scale_elements() - scale wrapper of my page.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case of someone will face this problem too, thats how I solved it.

I couldn't make it work with zoom, so i just turn off slider click tracking and push him to use only dragging(with dragging it work more correctly).

Turn off dragging is a bit complex to, that how i did it:

```
                if (scale < 100) { // detect zooming
                    $('.slider').css('height', '0px'); //setting height of slider to 0, so user can't click on it
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using the `slide` and `change` attributes in the `slider` constructor:

**HTML**

```
<div id="zoom-box">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<div id="debug"></div>  <!-- Remove for production -->
```

**CSS**

```
#slider {
    width: 363px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#slider').slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    width: 50,
    value: 100,
    slide: updateZoom,
    change: updateZoom
});

function updateZoom() {
    var scale = $('#slider').slider('value');
    $('#zoom-box').css('zoom', (scale) + '%');
    $('#debug').prepend(scale + '<br/>');  // Remove for production
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but thats not work for me, I dont need to zoom slider on slide or change event. The goal is to make slider work right in zoomed state, in example when you click on the right side of the slider from here http://jsfiddle.net/8hbMx/ , it will slide wrong.

Comment: Ah right - if you can assume an HTML5 compliant browser (Webkit or IE 10), then try `<input type="range" />` - the native HTML slider control

Comment: I can't, its need to be crossbrowser, but thanks for answering

Comment: No problem!  It appears as though the issue is with the jQueryUI slider control - maybe try looking on the jQuery forums?